# What does "idle dog" mean - is it slang or just a regional expression?

Tags: expressions, slang

I'm reading the book *The Wind in the Willows* by Kenneth Grahame, and I read this about a Mole:

> And instead of having an uneasy conscience pricking him and whispering ‘whitewash!’
> he somehow could only feel how jolly it was to be the only **idle dog** among all these busy citizens.

In Brazil, we have several regional expressions using the word "dog" , such “a dog’s life” to say "hard life".

But, what about  "[...]to be the only idle dog among all..."?

Comment: [What **does "idle dog" mean**? Use of present simple.]

Comment: You might like to note that a century or two ago, ***jolly*** was commonly used as an adjective meaning ***enjoyable***, but today [it's far more often](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+jolly+time%2Ca+jolly+good+time%2Ca+jolly+good&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) used as an "intensifier" like ***very, really,...*** . So *That was **a jolly good party**!* and *We had **a jolly good time** at the party* are still perfectly natural to many speakers, but the straightforward adjectival usage *We had **a jolly time** at the party* is uncommon today.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: "Jolly" as an intensifier sounds specifically British to me. In America I think it means "cheerful" but is mostly used to describe Santa Claus

Comment: @NickMatteo: Well, yes - it's certainly much more common in BrE than AmE. But if you switch to just the AmE corpus on that linked chart you'll see that the intensifier usage does occur there too. I think most Americans would understand *That was jolly difficult!* without getting confused with wondering what could be "cheerful" about a "difficult" task, though.

Comment: @FumbleFingers American here, without more context, I'd assume someone who said *That was jolly difficult!* really enjoyed the challenge of whatever they just did.

Comment: @NickMatteo - more common in BrE than AmE, but not excluded from the latter, especially on the east side: _He goes on and on --and with jolly good reason--about the lusty charms of North Carolina pork barbecue_ (1982 Washington Post review of 'American Taste' by James Villas)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'Dog' is just slang for '(usually) male person'. Especially at the time of writing (1908). Calling a man or boy a dog may be an insult or may not, but calling a girl woman a 'bitch' (a female dog) is almost always an insult in English-speaking countries.

*You: I am going to marry a blonde film star whose father is very rich.*
*Me:  You lucky dog!*

*Me:   I slept all day yesterday*
*You:  You lazy dog!*

*I am not working today; I am an idle dog while everyone else is working.*

> dog noun [C] (PERSON)   slang
>
> a person of a stated type:
>
> You won $1000? You lucky dog!

[Dog (noun) (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dog)

Comment: Some people, especially a woman dog breeder I know, get angry that the word 'bitch' is considered so bad that people are afraid to use with its original purpose.

Comment: The most common words used in [exclamatory *"You lucky xxx!"*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=You+lucky+*&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) (most popular first) are ***bastard, dog, thing, girl, devil, man,...*** The fact of the *top* choice being NSFW (and contextually arguably "peculiar" ***thing*** being in 3rd place) makes me suspect "euphemism" is a factor in the usage ***dog*** here. We don't often hear things like *You stupid dog!*, and offhand I can't think of *any* similar contexts where ***dog** (= **person**)* is common.

Comment: @FumbleFingers _You sly dog!_ is a reasonably common admiring comment e.g. when a male friend or colleague announces his forthcoming parenthood. Context can decide a lot: _You cowardly, lazy, idle, greedy, stupid, ignorant, foolish, lucky, sly, or mad dog!_ One can be (or aspire to be) _top dog_ esp. in a _dog eat dog_ world

Comment: I forgot *You **sly** dog!, You **old** dog!* and *You **dirty** dog!,* all of which still occur fairly naturally in my circles. Most if not all the others would probably sound a bit "affected" to me in ordinary conversational contexts today. I notice one of the presenters on GB News sometimes adopts / is dubbed *"**Big Dog**"*, which I think is quite "cute" (England's answer to Scotland's [***Big Yin***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Billy_Connolly) :).

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I forgot _old_ and _dirty_. In my youth an amusing fellow was sometimes called _a gay dog_. Heaven knows what youngsters make of that.

Comment: Any ideas why I'm getting downvotes on this answer? How could it be improved?

Comment: I haven't downvoted anything myself (just upvotes for the question, and this answer). I can't think *why* you got a couple of downvotes, but I see there are also two downvotes to Astralbee's answer, so maybe they're both from the same pair of dorks. But I have no idea why people who presumably want to learn *current* English should be more inclined to upvote an answer encouraging them to copy usages that are so obviously declining. Especially when *You lucky **dog**!* is normally "affectionate", but *You lucky **bitch**!* is very likely to cause offense.

Comment: "Trans wars" excepted, English is largely gender-neutral, but gender is significant in an awful lot of languages, so even though native Anglophones are unlikely to choose between ***dog*** and ***bitch*** there according to the sex of the person they're talking to, I don't find it impossible to suppose that at least *some* non-Anglophone learners might make that mistake in all innocence! You tell a guy he's a lucky dog, and he grins in agreement. But tell a girl she's a lucky bitch and you might get a slap round the face!

Answer (score 8):

An "idle dog" is a common metaphorical way to refer to a lazy *person*.

The fact that *Wind in the Willows* uses anthropomorphism (making animals human) as a literary device makes it a little unusual of course - he's a mole but being called a dog. You really have to view these separately. Although a mole, all animals in the novel could be viewed as allegories for people and their human traits, including being idle. In fact, unlike some other 'beast stories', the animals are presented as having human lives - Toad lives in a stately home and drives a car, for example - so arguably they are not animals but humans that embody the characteristics of the animals they are named for (eg the water vole enjoys the river, the badger is somewhat hermit-like).

Comment: ***Idle dogs*** was [still reasonably common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=idle+dogs&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=20) over a century ago when *The Wind In The Willows* was written. But apart from reprints, I wouldn't say it's common today.

Comment: @FumbleFingers First nitpick of the new year. It's common in literature.

Comment: Common in *Victorian* literature, as my linked chart clearly shows. Why vent your spleen on a comment that's potentially useful to learners who *don't* want to sound like a character in Dickens?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Queen Victoria died 7 years before the publication of *Wind in the Willows* so it isn't "Victorian literature". Further, this ngram demonstrates a recent resurgence in usage and it is almost as common today as it was in 1908. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=idle+dog&year_start=1908&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3

Comment: @Astralbee A lot of the recent Google Books results are false positives. Searching 2016-19, the first has a period in between idle and dog. The second is from Tales and Novels by Maria Edgeworth first published in 1857. The third is about an idle person observing dogs. The fourth is kinda gibberish but might count. The fifth is from Ambrose Bierce who disappeared in 1914. Etc.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - doesn't _everybody_ want to sound like a character in Dickens? ;-)

Comment: @StuartF if you're saying that 5 "false positives" could create a frequency comparable to a century ago then either the phrase wasn't that "common in Victorian literature" or the cohort of Google books is not reliable. Perhaps Fumble Finger needs to provide evidence for their claim.

Comment: @Astralbee: I've gone through several pages of results now, and haven't found a single true positive. Lots of reprints of old works, mostly.

Comment: Also, note that Google Books is the data source for your own ngrams graph. If you're going to say that Google Books isn't reliable, that means your own graph isn't reliable.

Comment: @user2357112 That's the very point I was making, o nameless one. I used the word "common" to mean commonly known or commonly understood. FumbleFingers made it about *frequency*, but without any evidence. Google Books is about all we have to evidence frequency of use in a selection of literature, but if we're looking at a graph based on only tens of publications in 100 years then nobody can refer to it. I'm still awaiting some robust evidence from Fingers for their claim, but it won't make a jot of difference to my answer because it's not about the count.

Comment: "I used the word "common" to mean commonly known or commonly understood." - but that's not what the word "common" means.

Comment: It may be commonly understood (though I’m not sure that’s really true either), but it is not common in modern-day English. I have never in my life heard anyone use the phrase ‘idle dog’ in conversation, and if I did, I would take it to mean ‘lazy bastard’ rather than ‘lazy person’ (i.e., with all the derogatory force of the word _dog_ applied to people in general, rather than the mollified meaning found in phrases like ‘sly dog’), precisely _because_ it’s not common. In Victorian-ish literature, I would understand it quite differently.

Comment: "lazy dog" is what one might say today. There is such a thing as creative writing. Not everything is already written.